# Método sum() en la versión cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

Necesito aplicar la función `sum()`, utilizo la versión `cakephp3` , tengo una tabla Facturas el cual posee un campo llamado montos, necesito sumar el contenido del mismo y que me retorne un valor que podríamos llamar total

Ejemplo: `120 + 120+10` total `250`

Aquí mi código

```
public function total()
    {
        $suma=$this->Facturas->find('all',
        array(
        'fields'=>'montos'
        ));
    $this->set('suma',$suma=$this->paginate($this->Facturas->find('all')));

        debug($suma);
   }
```

y me retorna lo siguiente

```
object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet) {

'items' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Factura) {

        'id' => (int) 5,
        'montos' => '66252',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2017-07-08T03:05:08+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2017-07-08T03:05:08+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Facturas'

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Factura) {

        'id' => (int) 10,
        'montos' => '4500',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2017-07-08T14:17:43+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2017-07-08T14:17:43+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Facturas'

    },
    (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\Factura) {

        'id' => (int) 20,
        'montos' => '15029',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2017-07-27T16:39:03+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2017-07-27T16:39:03+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

        },
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Facturas'

    }
  ]

 }
```

ADMINISTRADORA , montos acumulados , Conjuntos

Comment: notemos que el metodo find(all') como primer parámetro tiene 'all' pero al cambiarlo a list tampoco me muestra el total, alguien me podrá ayudar?? gracias

Comment: Para hacer una consulta sencilla contra una sola tabla y uno de sus campos, ¿porque no haces una consulta de tipo RAW?

Answer (score 1):

**Solución 1**

Puedes obtener todos los registros de la tabla con una query simple, e iterar, sumando los valores del campo para obtener lo que requieres:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$query = TableRegistry::get( 'Facturas' )->find();

$sum = 0;
foreach ( $query as $factura ) {
    $sum += $factura->montos;
}
```

**Solución 2**

Para usar la función **sum()**, prueba lo siguiente (creo que la primera opción es la que funciona, las pruebas y nos cuentas):

```
/* Opción 1 */
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$query = TableRegistry::get( 'Facturas' )
    ->find()
    ->select([ 'montos' ])
    ->sum([ 'montos' ]);

/* Opción 2 */
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$query = TableRegistry::get( 'Facturas' )
    ->find()
    ->select([ 'montos' ])
    ->sum();
```

**Solución 3**

En ***cake 2***, tenías la siguiente opción para ejecutar una consulta de tipo RAW. No se si se mantenga para la versión 3. Si funciona yo optaría por está, prefiero estos tipos de consultas por temas de rendimiento.

En el modelo:

```
$res = $this->query(
    "SELECT SUM( montos ) AS total FROM Facturas"
);
```

En el controlador:

```
$res = $this->FacturasModel->query(
    "SELECT SUM( montos ) AS total FROM Facturas"
);
```